# Changing the state of some part of the program

Tags: state

There is a lot of talk about changing state especially in web development. I hear parts of a page connected to something in the back end that need to change state when new information is available. What does it mean when a part of the code changes its state? Is it becoming something else or are granular parts of it, attributes only, changing?

Comment: Imagine you have a coffee machine, front end is buttons you see on the display, backend is some hidden software which listens to touch, select, etc. events. First you choose what type of coffee you want - the backend receives that information from display and changes its state to say "Coffee Type Selected", next you confirm your selection and backend changes to "Coffee Preparation", then you wait, the backend triggers pouring coffee, milk, water, etc. as per your choice ("Coffee pouring begin", "Coffee pouring end". Then, backend resets its state to "Awaiting inputs" - something like that.

Comment: So, what changed? Just the value of a variable, many variables, did a class change to a different class or did only attributes of that class change? The phrase "change of state" seems like an important concept but also incredibly vague. Does it just mean something changed? Or something changed because something happened?

Comment: Yes, change of state can be either changing values of variables or some change in behavior like trigger to some operation, change in UI, etc. It can also sometimes be like giving access to some operation which was not possible before, etc.